# How do I monitor IIS7 output caching?

Tags: iis-7, cache

I have dynamic content that I've configured output caching upon.  Based on my tests it doesn't seem like IIS is seeing the content as cache-worthy.  How can I monitor what IIS is doing?  It appears as though PerfMon has some counters I'm interested in, but I'm not sure which ones to look at.  If my content is not querystring or form parameter based, but URI based will my content not be deemed cache-worthy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this article:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/154/walkthrough-iis-70-output-caching/

Some highlights:

- Things aren't cached right away, they must be configured a few times to be considered cache-worthy. The [`ServerRuntime` config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690574) section determines cache-worthiness. (Defaults to 2 requests in 10 seconds to be added to the cache)
- The `Web Service Cache` perfmon counters are the relevant counters for output cache
- If you are using kernel mode caching, `netsh http show cachestate` will show you what is currently in the cache
- [Failed Request Event Buffering (FREB)](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/) can give you details about caching for each request

Comment: I read the same article, I've watched the counters and they aren't doing anything so my content must not be cache-worthy.  I'm running load tests with thousands of requests, any ideas as to why I'm not getting hits?

Comment: @foosnazzy: I think your best bet then would be the FREB logs - it should give you better details about why things are not being cached.

Comment: FREB logs are working for me, I can now see what is cached and what is not.